# Hiding multiple netrw files not working

Tags: netrw

I am trying to hide all dotfiles and all `.jsx` files from netrw

When I update the variable `g:netrw_list_hide`, nothing happens.

```
let ghregex = '\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'
let jsxregex = '.*\.jsx$'

let g:netrw_list_hide = ghregex
let g:netrw_list_hide = ',' . jsxregex
let g:netrw_hide = 1
```

When I run :echo `g:netrw_list_hide`, it gives me the default regex.

How can i troubleshoot this?

Also, the files are not hidden by default.

Comment: I'm not sure of the full answer, but note that `:let a = …` followed by `:let a = …` just overwrites the old value. If you mean to concat them, try `:let a .= …` on subsequent assignments, or use `:let a = b . ',' . c`, or `:let a = printf('%s,%s', b, c)`